# Did Smith infect everyone in the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix, agent-smith

One of the answers to another question ([Why did Seraph and Sati hide?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72520/why-did-seraph-and-sati-hide)) raised the point of programs using the backdoors to avoid getting copied by Smith.

I always assumed that Smith infected all the Matrix, based on Neo's talk to the Deus Ex Machina:

> The program *Smith* has grown beyond your control. Soon he will spread through this city, **as he spread through The Matrix**

Shouldn't we conclude that he really got access to *all of the Matrix*, including the backdoors? In that case, he would have infected even the Architect, right?

How can we know whether he did or did not?

Comment: Why would spread through the Matrix be the equivalent of infect the entire matrix? An infection is epidemic when it infects a certain percentage of the population. That is not the same as everyone is infected. The statement also states he will SOON spread through the Matrix. Suggest you rephrase to better fit the definition of the original statement.

Comment: @GenericGeek The statement implies that Smith has *already* spread through the Matrix and will *soon* spread through the City (i.e. the Machine City, 01).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Smith does have access to the backdoors:

[image]

But if the Architect stayed in his room then Smith could not have gotten to him because the Architect's room is locked by a special key that can only be used by The One:

> The Keymaker: Only The One can open the door. And only during that window can that door be opened.

Additionally, it is possible that Smith did not have access to [Mobil Avenue](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Mobil_Avenue), and even if he did [The Trainman](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Trainman) has absolute power there ("down here I'm God") and could prevent Smith from copying himself over to anyone in Mobil Avenue. The Trainman is loyal to the Merovingian, so presumably the Trainman, Merovingian, and all the Merovingian's exile minions would be safe from Smith in Mobil Avenue.

Comment: Once Neo enters the Architect's "Door of light", he's unmolested by Smith.

Comment: @Richard Right, which is why the Architect should be safe from Smith as long as he stays in his room.

Comment: Also the Merovingian can hide out in the Train Man's station until the whole thing blows over.

Comment: @Richard Yes, good point. I was thinking only of the Architect since that was specifically in the question. All the exiles friendly to the Merovingian would presumably be safe as well, also hiding out in Mobil Avenue.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's contribution... This was a very nice answer

Comment: @Null - He and his minions have survived multiple reboots, presumably by employing the same technique each time.

Comment: @Richard Indeed, that is how I've always assumed they survived reboots. The Merovingian as an information broker knows when the reboots will occur, so he can tell everyone when to retreat to Mobil Avenue.